# sendMail is not sending emails from the server

Tags: php, linux, server, sendmail, hosts

So, I have a server set up in Rackspace, which has Apache2 and PHP installed. A web site is hosted there with no problems. The website has a form that sends the information to an email using a php `mail()` function. The problem is that the `sendMailconfig` is giving me a problem with the host name. It says:

> Warning: local host name app1 is not qualified.

It uses the local host then, but the mail log says that `127.0.0.1` refused the connection, so the mail does not go away. This is my hosts file. I will put xxx on some numbers not to disclose private info:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.xxx.xxx.247  app1
162.xxx.xxx.164 app1
2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxxx:xxxx:xxx:3abc app1
```

If I try to change the name of the host to `app1.xxxx.com` which is a working domain since the web site is there, it tells me `hostname: Name or service not known`.

Any ideas why sendmail is not working?

Comment: The error pretty much says it all. `app1` is not an [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). This is pretty important when it comes to mail servers. Make sure to use `app1.example.com` as sending server (where example.com is your actual domain name).

Comment: First thing to check is if the server may send mails. Most VPS'ses (cloud instances) are not qualified to send mail at all. If you would try to, most server would bounce or blacklist the mails instantly. It would be smarter to setup the send mail service to use a smarthost (external mail server, you may need login) or, if you only intend to send mails every now and then, use a mailer like phpmailer and set it up to use the mail server you have at your ISP.